# SQL Query to CSV or EXCEL format

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm wanting to pull the following into an excel file, but can't.

```
select o.*
from (
    select 
        o.*,
        min(processed_at) over(partition by contact_email) min_processed_at,
        sum(total_price)  over(partition by contact_email) sum_total_price
    from (
        select 
            o.*,
            row_number() over(partition by id) instance
        from `windy-oxide-255921.lume_shopify.orders` o
    ) o
    where instance = 1
) o
where 
    processed_at between '2019-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' and '2019-02-01 00:00:00 UTC'
    and sum_total_price > 100
```

Is there a way I can make this exportable into a CSV or Excel format? Can anyone provide me with some guidance here? Should I be using the unnest function here somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with `but can't`? Is there any error message you see?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in SSMS:

Right-click on the upper left corner of the results grid, and save as CSV.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to export to [CSV](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_formats_and_compression_types), my suggestion is review the documentation about [Exporting table data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data), you need to consider the [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#required_permissions) and [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_limitations).

Exist multiple ways to perform this action for example using the BigQuery UI, CLI, API, or using client libraries like C#, Go, Python, Java, Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

When I need SQL results out in XLSX I use Python, in particular, I use Openpyxl.

https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/